# Symfony 4.3 error: You cannot set both "templating.hinclude_default_template" and "fragments.hinclude_default_template"

Tags: symfony

After Symfony 4.1 update to 4.3 I get templating deprecation warnings.
After reading https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-deprecated-the-templating-component-integration
I've removed templating and added fragments.

But now I get this error

> You cannot set both "templating.hinclude_default_template" and "fragments.hinclude_default_template", please only use "fragments.hinclude_default_template"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same error. It seems FOSUserBundle was still using templating. I was already planning to remove this bundle. When I removed FOSUserBundle the error went away. It may not be an option for you, but maybe it will help you find the problem.

Comment: I tought it has something to do with FOSUserBundle, but if I remove it, I get errors from FOS oauth bundle.